# In R, sample from a neighborhood according to scores

Tags: r, sample, quantile

I have a vector of numbers, and I would like to sample a number which is between a given position in the vector and its neighbors such that the two closest neighbors have the largest impact, and this impact is decreasing according to the distance from the reference point.

For example, lets say I have the following vector:

```
 vec = c(15, 16, 18, 21, 24, 30, 31)
```

and my reference is the number 16 in position #2. I would like to sample a number which will be with a high probability between 15 and 16 or (with the same high probability) between 16 and 18. The sampled numbers can be floats. Then, with a decreasing probability to sample a number between 16 and 21, and with a yet lower probability between 16 and 24, and so on.

The position of the reference is not known in advance, it can be anywhere in the vector.

I tried playing with runif and quantiles, but I'm not sure how to design the scores of the neighbors.

Specifically, I wrote the following function but I suspect there might be a better/more efficient way of doing this:

```
GenerateNumbers <- function(Ind,N){
    dist <-  1/abs(Ind- 1:length(N))
    dist <-  dist[!is.infinite(dist)]
    dist <- dist/sum(dist)
    sum(dist) #sanity check --> 1

    V = numeric(length(N) - 1)
    for (i in 1:(length(N)-1)) {
      V[i] = runif(1, N[i], N[i+1])
    }
    sample(V,1,prob = dist)
}
```

where Ind is the position of the reference number (16 in this case), and N is the vector. "Dist" is a way of weighing the probabilities so that the closer neighbors have a higher impact.

Improvements upon this code would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Could you expand on what you tried so far?

Comment: @Vincent Guillemot, please see edit to my question

Comment: I don't think there is much to improve, it looks already fine. Maybe someone will have an idea. What would you like to improve?

Comment: Also, see here for some useful info https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171592/generate-random-numbers-with-linear-distribution

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a truncated Gaussian random sample generator, such as in the [`truncnorm`](https://github.com/olafmersmann/truncnorm) package. On your example:

```
# To install it: install.package("truncnorm")
library(truncnorm)
vec <- c(15, 16, 18, 21, 24, 30, 31)
x <- rtruncnorm(n=100, a=vec[1], b=vec[7], mean=vec[2], sd=1)
```

The histogram of the generated sample fulfills the given prerequisites.

[image: Histogram]

Comment: Vincent, sd =1 doesn't consider the fact that the distance to the neighbor on the left is different from the neighbor on the right. Also, like this the probability of ever reaching beyond 19 is practically 0 - disregarding the 4th neighbor and beyond

Comment: Yes, in this solution, the distribution is "locally" symmetric around the mean. I think you need to show us a drawing of what you expect the probability mass function to look like.